# Error running macro after trying to run it from pesonal workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros, csv

So I wrote a macro. The scenario of use is:

- I open a fresh and new CSV file downloaded from somewhere
- My macro runs and does some magic with the data

Since I don't want to copy-paste my macro to each one of the new CSV files I found out that I can move this macro to the hidden `PERSONAL.XLSB` workbook, which I did. Unfortunatelly, when trying to invoke this macro form the CSV file some error occur - I don't know why.

Here is the problematic framgent of the code:

```
 Sub copySheet()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy _
    After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(1).Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "X1"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = "X2"

End Sub
```

Here is the error I get:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Copy method of Worksheet class failed

Answer (score 0):

I found the soliton myself. It seems that my code tried to run the copy opeation on the Personal workbook instead of running it on the active one. This is the solution:

```
Private Sub copySheet()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy _
    After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(1).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "X1"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = "X2"

End Sub
```